# Performance - Method concatenates strings using + in a loop

Tags: java, sonarqube

I'm encountering this issue on this line of code even I use .append() inside the loop.

```
for (final FieldError fieldError : result.getFieldErrors()) {
    errors = new StringBuilder(errors).append(fieldError.getField()).append(" - ")
     .append(getErrorMessageFromProperties(fieldError.getCode())).append("*").toString();
}
```

how can I fix this?

Comment: Performance - Method concatenates strings using + in a loop

Comment: @james you are trying to optimize an error?

Comment: You probably want to assign a new string builder to error *before* the loop and reuse it

Comment: @ChrisK yes i want to optimize the error

Comment: @james optimize the common cases, everything else is premature.  if your error rate is high enough to be significant, then you will be best to reduce the error rate than to optimize a few concatenations.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create `StringBuilder` outside the `for` loop and reuse it.

```
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
for (final FieldError fieldError : result.getFieldErrors()) {
      sb.append(fieldError.getField())
           .append(" - ")
           .append(getErrorMessageFromProperties(fieldError.getCode()))
           .append("*");
 }
```

After appending all to `sb` you can call

```
 String error=sb.toString()
```

just after the `for` loop

Answer (score 1):

Each time you want to read a database table, you use a loop. As database tables grow along the time, the number of iterations in the loop grow accordingly. So you want to avoid any operation in the iterations that could be costly in terms of performance. Furthermore, this is the kind of defect that you cannot detect during QA or when the application is young, with a test database that has few records.

Avoid string concatenation, creation of objects in memory, etc. in a loop.